# Dictionary to string

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have dictionary `"a Dictionary(#DOB->Date #Name->String #Salary->Number )"`. I need to create a string which should be `str:= "DOB Date,Name String,Salary Number"` . I tried using `keysAndValuesDo`: but couldn't concatenate them correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in a nice way like this:

```
(dict associations collect: [ :assoc |
  assoc key asString, ' ', assoc value asString ])
    joinUsing: $,
```

if you want to use #do: and streams, you can go this way:

```
dict associations
  do: [ :assoc |
    aStream
      nextPutAll: assoc key asString;
      space;
      nextPutAll: assoc value asString ]
  separatedBy: [ aStream nextPut: $, ]
```

please note that in case you want to delegate printing to the object itself and not convert it to string and put in on the stream manually, you can use:

```
aStream
  print: assoc key;
  ....
```

`#print:` method of a stream sends `#printOn:` to the parameter. `#printOn:` is the defat method you have to override to make your object properly printable on a stream. `#asString` uses `#printOn:` for a lot of objects.

Comment: @Harshit you are welcome, I've also added snippet that uses #do: strategy

Comment: Shouldn’t it be #nextPutAll: instead of #print:? The use of #print: results in '#Name ''PString'',#DOB ''Date'',#Salary ''Number'''

Comment: @MartinW thank you for comment. I was thinking about a general situation where each object should be print itself in it's own way. Fixed answer now

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with keysAndValuesDo too. Just remember that a Dictionary isn't ordered, and there is no nice keysAndValuesDo:separatedBy:

```
|dict first str|
dict := OrderedIdentityDictionary 
    newFromPairs:#(#DOB Date #Name String #Salary Number).
first := true.
str := String streamContents: [  :s |
    dict keysAndValuesDo: [ :key :value |
        first ifFalse: [ s nextPutAll: ',' ]
            ifTrue: [ first := false].
        s   nextPutAll: key; space;
            nextPutAll: '';
            nextPutAll: value] ].
str

'DOB Date,Name String,Salary Number'
```

Comment: and how could we obtain `'Date','Name','salary'` by using same dictionary.

Comment: Why do you want keys and values mixed? And capitalized and lowercased mixed? If you want to add quotes, use nextPutAll: ''''